# Change Background color of second para in the same p tag

Tags: html, css

Wanted to know if it is possible to change the background color of the second paragraph in the same p element
[image]

```html
<span class="trim-last-paragraph">
        <p><strong>Lorem Ipsum</strong>is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.<br><br><strong>Lorem Ipsum</strong>is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.</p>
      </span>
```

I know it is possible with different p tags using the nth-child

Thank you for your help! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe change your approach to it. Separate the p tags by its sentences then use [:nth-child()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child) If you know the exact position of the child element.

```css
.paragraphs p:nth-child(2) {
  background: orange;
}
```

```html
<div class="paragraphs">
  <p>
    <strong>Lorem Ipsum</strong>is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. 
  </p>
  <p>
    <strong>Lorem Ipsum</strong>is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.
  </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

```html
  <body>

    <span class="trim-last-paragraph">
        <p><strong>Lorem Ipsum</strong>
            is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.<br><br>
        </p><p style="background-color: goldenrod"><strong>Lorem Ipsum</strong>is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.</p>
      
    </p>
    </span>
   
       
  </body>
```

Comment: Please explain your code further. Thanks